# Session is lost after forwarding the request from action class in one application to jsp in another application

Tags: session, struts2, forward

I am trying to forward to a jsp in application2 from an action class in application1. Both applications are running in the same servlet container (glassfish 2.1). Though I could successfully forward to and display the jsp, I was not able to retrieve the attribute/object from the session that was set in application1 before executing the forward api of the ServletActionContext. I printed the sessionID in the jsp in application2 and it exactly matches with the id that I printed in application1. So, I assume my session was not disturbed between this transition. Then what is happening to the session variables?. Why/How they became null?.

Here is the code:

```
    request.getSession().setAttribute("commonQuestions", "abc");
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

    // Change the servletcontext to the second application 
    ServletActionContext.setServletContext(ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getContext("/TYP_PFRS_ETP"));

    // Define request dispatcher for resource in second application
    RequestDispatcher rd = 
        ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/helloworld.jsp");

    rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Do you have some form of session sharing set up? Otherwise the two apps shouldn't know *anything* about sessions in other apps.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not sure what you mean... As per the spec, HttpSession is created on the server on behalf of a user who makes a request to the server. A handle to this session is preserved either in cookies or through URL rewriting across multiple requests. This session handle represented by a sessionID, is not attached / linked to a specific application and is transported via the request object. Also, Servlet spec clearly says that "Forward" API will not create a new session and rather preserves the old one unlike the "Redirect" API.

Comment: Apps do not share session data unless your app server is specifically configured to do so. It would be madness otherwise; every app would have to make sure not to overwrite another app's data, or if it did, you'd never be able to track down what broke a particular app. An app container can serve an arbitrary number of apps, and those apps are isolated from each other, unless things are specifically configured otherwise.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Though what you clarified makes sense and appreciate it, I have been looking for a clear and specific mention of that constraint(session scope) in any Spec / API documentation. I guess I finally found it here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/tecbkgnd.htm